# SpringMVC Custom Getter Method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to specify a custom Getter method in SpringMVC binding, rather than the default PropertyDescriptors?

I feel like I'm venturing into outer space with this question, sounds so simple and yet no Google results. I'm doing this because my model has a `Boolean` has a getter named `isSomething()` and SpringMVC will only check that for primitive booleans. For the class `Boolean` it'll complain that a getter is not found, it requires `getSomething()`.

I should be able to just specify custom getters/setters if I need those, isn't that the case?

Since I know people will suggest custom Property Editors etc., I put a breakpoint in these methods, and **it doesn't even get here** -- the problem happens somewhere up the chain, with `PropertyDescriptor`s:

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(Boolean.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getValue();
    }



});
```

I wanted to play with these custom editors, but the code never gets here. The error is thrown before that.

> Invalid property 'test' of bean class [Model]: Bean property 'test' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

How can I achieve this fairly common scenario of custom getters/setters?

Comment: did you add you custom register to CustomEditorConfigurer?